# modal on appears after each item is clicked..can only loop the first item,then function doesnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I wanted to create as pop up modal after each button has been clicked on saying, you have clicked on all the buttons. I got the modal window to pop up with just one button but I cannot get the the rest of the other buttons to load when I create the same class. Please help,thanks

```
<div class="container">

    <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="mybox modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class=" mybox modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>



    <div class="modal fade" id="win" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">You won</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Congrats.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

</div>




<script>
    var Boxes = [];
    var ttle = $('.mybox').length;
    $('.mybox').click(function () {
        var bx = this.id;
        if (Boxes.indexOf(bx) >= 0) {
            $("#myMod").modal("toggle");
        } else {
            Boxes.push(bx);
        }
        if (Boxes.length == ttle) {
            $("#win").modal("toggle");
        }

    });

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#myBtn").click(function(){
            $("#myModal").modal();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you please add your JS code?

Comment: just edited,sorry about that thanks

Comment: To clarify, what is the unintended behaviour here? When I test it, it works fine the first time and goes through all the modals, but is buggy and instantly closes the second modal with subsequent clicks. Is this what you mean, or is there something else?